# Sprite Kit - World not in drawing sprites in correct position despite skview with right dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to draw a basic ground to the game for my sprite to run on.
But it seems that the ground is too short although it is suppose to take up 1/3 of the height of the screen.

My GameScene.sks is already changed to 568x320 (landscape, iPhone 5/5S)

this is my current code

```
func initMainGround() {
    let gSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width/4*3*2, 120);
    let ground = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.brownColor(), size: gSize);
    ground.name = gName; //Ground
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: gSize);
    ground.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.friction = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
    ground.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false;
    ground.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true; //accurate collision
    ground.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false;
    ground.physicsBody.dynamic = false;
    ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = gBitmask; // 0x1 << 0
    ground.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pBitmask; //0x1 << 1        playerCategoryBitmask

    self.addChild(ground);
}
```

`NSLog(String(self.size.height))` return `320.0` which is perfectly fine.
But why is it that the `SKSpriteNode` is draw wrongly?

Setting the height of the ground to `320` only fills up half of the screen although the height of the screen in landscape is 320.

Comment: CGPointMake(0, 0) is the bottom-left corner of your scene. CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) is the center of your scene. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Comment: Well the function simply add a ground at the start for the player to run on, after that more grounds would appear for the player to jump on. Putting it in the middle is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Like Jon said, this is a placement issue not a size issue. The default anchor point of any given node is in its center, so you have two options here:

1) set ground.position to `CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))`
(or even better yet, capture that as an ivar, because you'll be referring to it a whole lot when adding things to your screen, and there's no real reason to do the calculations dozens of times)

2) change the anchor point of the ground node. This is done as a CGPoint, but is interpreted as a percentage of the size of the node in question, with the default (center) being (0.5, 0.5). `ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero` (which is just a shortcut for `CGPointMake(0, 0)`) will set the node's anchor point to its lower-left corner, at which point setting its position to (0,0) will correctly place it starting at the lower-left corner of your scene (or its parent node, in any event).

Comment: Using your second answer, it seems that my sprite simply jump into the ground, and stands inside the ground, it drops after the ground disappears from the screen. I guess the physical body size does not match the actual size show on the screen?

Comment: You can use "showsPhysics" to see the actual physicsBody. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/showsPhysics

Comment: Where are you setting the anchor point? It needs to be done before you instantiate the physicsBody, or else the physicsBody will probably be in the wrong place. In this case, I'm guessing that the physicsBody is still centered on a (0.5, 0.5) anchor (the ground node's center), which would have half of it off-screen, and explain your player node "standing inside" of it.

Comment: It is done just before instantiate the position of the ground

Comment: @Jon after using showsPhysics, the physics body are at the wrong place, the drawn boxes are now correctly drawn

Comment: The boxes is now drawn correctly, but the physical body is still wrong

Comment: You may have to show the code where you are setting anchorpoint. I have problems w/ anchorpoints and physicsbodies myself, so I may not be able to help out here.

Comment: short of posting your code for us to debug further, you could look to see if there's a swift equivalent to the objc [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: center:] method, to fix the misplacement.